# Insert empty values to wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have my form like this:

```
<div id="titlewrap">
    <label class="" id="title-prompt-text" for="title">Enter title here</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" size="30" value="" id="title" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<br class="clear">
<?php
    $mva_content = '';
    $editor_id = 'editor';
    $settings = array('media_buttons' => false);
    wp_editor($mva_content, $editor_id, $settings);
?>
```

If I show html source code with `CTRL+U` it looks like this:

```
<form action="admin.php?page=list" method="post">
    <div id="poststuff">
        <div id="post-body">
            <div id="post-body-content">
                <div id="titlediv">
                    <div id="titlewrap">
                        <label class="" id="title-prompt-text" for="title">Enter title here</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" size="30" value="" id="title" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <br class="clear">
                    <div id="wp-editor-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap html-active"><link rel='stylesheet' id='editor-buttons-css'  href='http://localhost/plug/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css?ver=4.0.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<div id="wp-editor-editor-tools" class="wp-editor-tools hide-if-no-js"><div class="wp-editor-tabs"><a id="editor-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);">Text</a>
<a id="editor-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);">Visual</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wp-editor-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container"><textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="20" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="editor" id="editor"></textarea></div>
</div>

                    <p class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" name="create" id="create" class="button button-primary" value="Add New Video Ad">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to save to my wordpress database after click on a save button:

```
global $wpdb;
$title = $_POST["title"];
$content = $_POST["editor"];
$wpdb->insert("mytable", array(
   "title" => $title,
   "content" => $content,
));
```

I see that in the database there is a row with incremented `id` but empty value in `title` and `content` columns.

i have tried to put Strings instead of `$_POST` variables and it works perfectly!

Is there an error with my code?

Comment: `PHP` only runs on the server, while the form will be run in the user's browser.  What does the `HTML` look like in the browser?  ie, can you show the full `<form>` section as the browser would receive it (you can use "view page source" from the browser to see it without `PHP`).

Comment: @stvcisco: i have edited the post  with the source code of the full html form. Actually, i dont think that is the root cause because if i use strings like `"test title"` instead of `$_POST["title"]` it works !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `print_r( $_POST )`.  Are the values getting to the script?

Try this really quick...

> NOTE: I added the %s to the end of the insert.

```
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $wpdb->insert("mytable", array(
       "title" => $title,
       "content" => $content,
    ), '%s');   
    $wpdb->print_error();
```

---

> **ON PREPARED STATEMENTS**

---

Look into using prepared statements.  (You should be using them anyway.)

[Wordpress WPDB Prepared Statements](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

[Wordpress Data Validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database)

Prepared Statement Example...

```
$metakey    = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue  = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        10, 
    $metakey, 
    $metavalue 
) );
```

Comment: I retried to get the coma off, the issue is always here. But the %s added to the end of the insert works perfectly ! thanks